# Scala - Scanleft, returning values within iterations without using it in a next turn

Tags: scala, list, api, foldleft

I have a list

what I would like to do is

```
def someRandomMethod(...): ... = {
  val list = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
  if(list.isEmpty) return list
  list.differentScanLeft(list.head)((a, b) => {
     a * b
  })
}
```

which returns
List(1, 2, 6, 12, 20) rather than List(1, 2, 6, 24, 120)

Is there such API?

Thank you,
Cosmir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`scan` is not really the right method for this, you want to use `sliding` to generate a list of adjacent pairs of values:

```
(1::list).sliding(2).map(l => l(0)*l(1))
```

More generally, it is sometimes necessary to pass data on to the next iteration when using `scan`. The standard solution to this is to use a tuple `(state, ans)` and then filter out the state with another `map` at the end.

Comment: selecting this answer as per it's conciseness.

Comment: This solution also has the advantage that it doesn't require the list to be in a variable, it can be applied directly to the output of an earlier operation.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use `zip`

```
val list = List(1,2,3,4,5,6)
val result = list.zip(list.drop(1)).map{case (a,b) => a*b}
println(result)

> List(2, 6, 12, 20, 30)
```

Comment: Using `tail` is dangerous unless you know the list is not empty. Prefer `drop(1)` if there is any doubt.